# Wordpress webpage taking a long time to connect to domain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, dns, connection

I developed a [site](http://moderngunrepair.com/) for a client of mine that seemed very solid on our servers (hostgator). But when I transferred the site over to there servers, it seems to take forever to connect to the site.

I am not sure if this is a server side issue, or the webpage it self. Could any one direct me in the direction on where to start to look? Or what the issue is?

Comment: The issue is most likely caused by their servers. You should see if the server is under heavy load, turn on caching in Wordpress and suggest a server change to your client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some reasons for the slowness of your site.

1)Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content

Your page has 8 blocking script resources and 13 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page. None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML.

2)Reduce server response time

Your server responded in 4.5 seconds. There are many factors that can slow down your server response time.

3)Leverage browser caching

Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.

[Full Details](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http://www.moderngunrepair.com/)

Comment: For the past few hours, I messed around with a few different things that increased my overall speed. But there is one thing that I am having trouble with. Leverage browser caching by using the .htaccess seems to not be working for me. I followed these steps http://www.wpcub.com/leverage-browser-caching-wordpress-via-htaccess/ and for some reason pagespeed is still docking me.